# Error accessing a class in another plugin (error: undefined reference)

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I'm trying to access a class, **`MyExternalClass`** in another plugin:

```
#include "../my_plugin/my_plugin.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    myExternalClass(new MyExternalClass)
{
}
```

**In the plugin**

```
#include "my_plugin.h"

MyExternalClass::MyExternalClass(QWidget *parent)
{
}
```

I, however, get the error:

```
/path/mainwindow.cpp:31: error: undefined reference to `MyExternalClass::MyExternalClass(QWidget*)'

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I getting wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: May be MyExternalClass doesnt have default constructor you shoud do it like MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    myExternalClass(new MyExternalClass(parent))
{
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined references are linkage errors. You need to link to your plugin library.

But this is not the general way to work with plugin. In general the main program defines a set of header files that define a comon interface. If you want to have the interface base classes to have function, it should also provide a library for the plugin library to link to. If you want the base classes to inherit from QWidget you will need to provide a library because of Qt's auto-generated methods. And alternative is to just ask the plugin for a QWidget and then communicate through signal/slot, and this way you don't need to provide the library.

Then the plugins link to that library, and define classes that inherit from the provided interface. In runtime you then dynamically load the plugin library, get the interface objects it provides somehow, e.g. through an extern "C" method, and then communicate using that.

Also, since you have a QWidget in your sample, take look at the [Qt manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) for plugins.